# What is the procedure to send solutions of Eudyptula challenge?

Tags: linux-kernel, email-attachments, thunderbird, eudyptula-challenge

I am trying to send solution to Task1 of **Eudyptula** Challenge. I have linked **thunderbird** to my registered gmail account and while sending the mail, I set **"Plain text" format and UTC encoding**. But I am getting a mail from little penguin as follows:
**"You sent me base64 attachments, which I can not understand at all :("**
Can anyone please suggest what is needed to change?

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird go to Edit->Preferences->Display->Font->Advanced and set Outgoing Mail to "Western (ISO-8859-1)".